Indesign how can I copy a master-page as a new page in the same document
I have a master page:
var master = doc.masterSpreads.itemByName("B-Parent");

I want that as a new page after my last page. I dont want that new page have that assigned master page "B-Parent", I want that new page be a copy of the master-page, having all items the master page has itself, but not the Items that the master-page inherits from its master-page:
So, if B-Parent has some text-frames and and an image and has itself the A-Parent as master which has some background etc., the new page should end up mastered by A-parent (B-Parents master) and should have a copy of B-Parents text-frames and its image.
How can I do that?
var master = doc.masterSpreads.itemByName("B-Parent");
var newPage = doc.pages.add();
/*
... how can I copy the content of master into newPage? ...
*/
newPage.appliedMaster = master.appliedMaster;


https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/need-script-to-insert-pages-with-specified-master/m-p/2200082 -- I don't want to simply copy/paste that as an answer here.

@Scott I cant see any script there relevant to my question? how can I copy the >>>content<<< of master into newPage

Oh sorry. Guess I misread.. you could apply the master to a page.. then override all master objects... same result as copying master contents to a doc page.

@Scott And how do I "override all master objects"…?

These questions can all be answered via google: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/js-override-alle-master-page-items/td-p/1900888 --No one here is likely to write a script for you.
